# python: filter dictionaries with matching string in specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Using Python3, i am trying to filter dictionaries based on matching a specifc value's starting numbers..

```
X = [{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'}, {'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'}, {'A1': 'string3', 'A2': 'dwsdwd', 'A3': '+643927213'}]
```

for more visibility:

```
for record in X:
    print(record)
```

output:

```
{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'}
{'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'}
{'A1': 'string3', 'A2': 'dwsdwd', 'A3': '+643927213'}
```

I would like to filter those dictionaries which has 'A3' parameter's value starts with +44, +54 as mentioned in below file.

cat codes.txt

```
+44
+54
```

Expected output:

```
{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'}
{'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'}
```

i have already tried below but no luck.. please help.

```
with open("codes.txt") as f:
    codes = f.read().splitlines()

for i in range(len(X)): 
    for code in codes:
        if code in X[i]['A3']: 
            del X[i] 
            break
```

Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of outputting them, you're deleting them `del X[i]`, why?

Comment: Sorry,, that was wrong.. i was trying other-way round..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the already given answer, imo you should check if `A3` exists in the first place:

```
result = [item for item in X
          if "A3" in item and item["A3"].startswith(("+44", "+54"))]

print(result)
# [{'A1': 'string1', 'A3': '+442186212', 'A2': 'khdskah'}, {'A1': 'string2', 'A3': '+54362831', 'A2': 'jgsajg'}]
```

With this approach, even elements without `A3` could be filtered:

```
X = [{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'},
     {'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'},
     {'A1': 'string3', 'A2': 'dwsdwd', 'A3': '+643927213'},
     {'some_weird_key': None}]
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to over-complicate things with redundant loops:

just make `codes` a *tuple* to be applied in [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) function:

```
codes = tuple(f.read().splitlines())
...

res = [d for d in X if d['A3'].startswith(codes)]
```

---

```
>>> res
[{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'}, {'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'}]
```

Comment: Nifty to pass the tuple to `startswith()`.

Comment: Plus one for the tuple thingy. However I'd check if the key exists in the first place (what about entries without `A3` ?).

Comment: @Jan, as for records "without `A3`" - it's not preliminary clear whether such entries should fall into resultset as default OR filtered out. That's the moment the OP needs to carry about and ask additionally if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension to filter your list:

```
filtered = [elem for elem in X if elem['A3'][:3] in codes]
```

Comment: This won't work - the codes txt file only includes the first bit of the phone number.

Comment: Right. The condition needs to be refined.

Answer (score 1):

```
X = [{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'}, {'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'}, {'A1': 'string3', 'A2': 'dwsdwd', 'A3': '+643927213'}, {'A1': 'string3', 'A2': 'dw', 'A3': '+4439272'}]
#

with open("codes.txt") as f:
    codes = f.read().splitlines()

    for v in X:
        for c in codes:
    #print(v['A3'][:3])
            if(c==v['A3'][:3]):
                print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.get('A3') and x['A3'].startswith(("+44", "+54")), X))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X = [{'A1': 'string1', 'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212'}, {'A1': 'string2', 'A2': 'jgsajg', 'A3': '+54362831'}, {'A1': 'string3', 'A2': 'dwsdwd', 'A3': '+643927213'}]
    codes=['+44','+64']
    # filtered = [elem for elem in X if elem['A3'][:3] in codes]

    filtered = [elem for elem in X if  [cod for cod in codes if cod== elem['A3'][:3]]]


    print(filtered)
```

> Output:[{'A2': 'khdskah', 'A3': '+442186212', 'A1': 'string1'}, {'A2':
>   'dwsdwd', 'A3': '+643927213', 'A1': 'string3'}]